# Restore lost commits when a merge was done wrong

Tags: git

I have a master and alternative branch with these commits :

```
A --- B --- C --- D (master)
       \
        E --- F --- G (sprint1)
```

Something wrong happened when the merge was done and some commits were lost, and people continuous to commit on branch:

```
A --- B --- E --- F --- G --- (M) (master)

A --- B --- E --- F --- G --- (M) --- H --- I (master)
```

What is the better way to do that ?

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- E --- F --- G --- H --- I
```

I am thinking to do git rebase, but in this way I have a lot of conflicts to resolve.

Comment: The graph that you are showing implies that you already did a rebase.  A merge would produce a graph where the two branches come together. For a merge, there are no lost commits.

Comment: do you still have a reference pointing to the lost commits?

Comment: Update your question with the branch names for `D` and `G` and `(M)` and `I`.

Comment: I have the pointing to the lost commits but there are a lot of

Comment: Half solution: use `git reflog` to find the commits `C` and `D`, e.g you might find that `D == dead00d`.  Then create a temporary branch `git branch ONCE-WAS-LOST dead00d`.  Now you have your "lost" commits back, and you can start thinking about how to get them into the new master.

Answer (score 0):

### Restating the problem

So the current state of your repo is:

```
A --- B --- C --- D ------
       \                  \
        E --- F --- G --- (M) --- H --- I --...-- Z (master)
```

But the merge was not successful, so the changes represented by `C` & `D` are
not properly incorporated into the current `master` branch.

### Can't be done (without causing pain)

Unfortunately you will not be able to reach the following state:

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- E' --...-- Z' (master)
```

without causing problems for every person who has pulled the current `master`
branch into their own repo.

### All is not lost

There are, however, a number of ways you could achieve a similar result (but I
can't promise there won't be any merge conflicts). From your comments, I am
going to assume you do know the refs for the missing commits. For convenience,
I am also going to assume you have tagged the following commits:

```
$ git tag <ref-to-D> oldmaster
$ git tag <ref-to-G> premerge
$ git tag <ref-to-H> postmerge
```

### Lose the chronology

If you don't really care about maintaining the chronology of the commits (ie
`A --- B --- C --- D --- E --...`) the easiest route would probably be to
rebase onto the current `master`:

```
$ git checkout oldmaster

$ git rebase master
  # deal with any merge-conflicts

$ git push origin master
  # get it out there before anyone else extends the branch further!
```

If all goes to plan, your branch will now look like:

```
A --- B --- E --- F --...-- Z --- C' --- D' (master)
```

### Overstating the pain of conflict?

If you really want to maintain the chronology, let's try rebasing onto the old
`master`:

*(depending on how it failed, the original merge may cause problems for this
approach. If so, we'll deal with that in the third approach)*

```
$ git checkout master

$ git rebase oldmaster
  # deal with any merge-conflicts
```

This is the time of conflicts which you feared... but it may not be that
painful. Git is usually very good at coping with differences between branches,
so there may not be much manual intervention required here.

Once that is done, your branch will look like this:

```
A --- B --- C --- D -------- E' --- F' --...-- Z' (master)
       \                  \
        E --- F --- G --- (M) --- H --...-- Z (origin/master)
```

The big problem we now face is that everyone else thinks `Z` is head of the
`master` branch. You can't force your new `master` onto other people, without
causing much pain and suffering. Probably the neatest thing to do now would be:

```
$ git merge -s ours origin/master
  # this creates a merge commit between the two master branches, but the file
  # contents will be identical to our new master branch

$ git push origin master
```

Now the picture should be:

```
A --- B --- C --- D -------- E' --- F' --...-- Z' --- (M2) (master)
       \                  \                           /     (origin/master)
        E --- F --- G --- (M) --- H --...-- Z --------
```

### Take it step by step

Maybe you liked the previous results, but there were just too many conflicts.
Or maybe that previous failed merge raised its ugly head and caused problems.

Let's try one final approach, taking it in smaller steps. First of all, let's
create the branch which we should have had at the time of the original merge:

```
$ git checkout oldmaster

$ git rebase premerge
  # remember I "assumed" you had tagged those refs?
  # deal with any merge-conflicts
```

We should now be looking at this state:

```
A --- B --- C --- D -------- E' --- F' --- G' (oldmaster)
       \                  \
        E --- F --- G --- (M) --- H --- I --...-- Z (master)
```

We are going to skip that merge commit and attempt to bring in commits `H`–`Z`.
Because you're here, I'm feeling a little cautious so I'm going to bring `H` in
on its own first:

```
$ git cherry-pick postmerge
  # deal with any merge-conflicts
```

If there are going to be any difficult conflicts, they will probably be here.
You will still need to resolve them, but at least they only represent one
commit (he says, knowing he doesn't have to merge them himself!).

The tree should now look like:

```
A --- B --- C --- D -------- E' --- F' --- G' --- H' (oldmaster)
       \                  \
        E --- F --- G --- (M) --- H --- I --...-- Z (master)
```

Ready for the final push? We're going to bring in the remaining commits from
master then, as before, create a merge commit so we can safely bring the other
users onto the new branch:

```
$ git cherry-pick postmerge..master

$ git merge -s ours master
```

This should result in:

```
A --- B --- C --- D -------- E' --- F' --...-- Z' --- (M2) (oldmaster)
       \                  \                           /
        E --- F --- G --- (M) --- H --...-- Z --------
                                           (master)
```

Because we were working on the `oldmaster` branch, we'll need to fast-forward
the real `master` branch before pushing back:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge oldmaster
  # fast-forward merge

$ git push origin master
```

And that should be that!